# How to read a list of strings in a H5py file?

Tags: python, string, list, h5py

The code below is used to generate a HDF5 file and I would like to retrieve a list of strings in the file:

```
import h5py
myfile = 'mytest.hdf'
mylist = ['abc1','def2'] 
with h5py.File(myfile,'w') as hdf:
    h5pylist = [n.encode('utf-8') for n in mylist]
    hdf.create_dataset('mylist',(len(h5pylist),1),'S10',h5pylist)
```

After the hdf file is created, I tried to use the following code to read the list in the hdf file:

```
with h5py.File(myfile,'r') as hdf:
    ls = list(hdf.keys())
    mynewlist = hdf.get(ls[0])
```

Here mynewlist is an hdf object. I don't know how to read it. I tried the following code but failed.

```
newlist = []
utf8_type = h5py.string_dtype('utf-8',30)
for mystr in mynewlist:
    newlist.append(np.array(mystr.encode('utf-8', dtype = utf8_type)))
```

I received an error

> 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0):

You're close...The dataset object behaves much like a NumPy array. I added some code to show how to access each and the similarity (`dset` is a H5 object and `arr` is a NumPy array of the dataset.) So, to operate on the individual strings you need to use an index to each value (you index the dataset or the array in the same way).

Here is the code to extract the contents of the dataset, decode and save to a new list.
Note: you don't need to create a List to access the keys (H5 object names). `.keys()` is an iterable, so you can use in a `for` loop.

```
myfile = 'mytest.hdf'
with h5py.File(myfile,'r') as hdf:
    for ls in hdf.keys() :
        # Get the dataset object:
        dset = hdf[ls]
        print (dset.shape, dset.dtype)
        # Get a NumPy array of the dataset
        arr = hdf[ls][:]
        print (arr.shape, arr.dtype)
        print (arr)

        newlist = []
        utf8_type = h5py.string_dtype('utf-8',30)
        for i in range(dset.shape[0]):
           mystr = dset[i][0].decode('utf-8')
           print(mystr)
           newlist.append(dset[i][0].decode('utf-8'))
           print (newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [79]: import h5py
    ...: myfile = 'mytest.hdf'
    ...: mylist = ['abc1','def2']
    ...: with h5py.File(myfile,'w') as hdf:
    ...:     h5pylist = [n.encode('utf-8') for n in mylist]
    ...:     hdf.create_dataset('mylist',(len(h5pylist),1),'S10',h5pylist)
    ...:
```

Looking at the file:

```
In [80]: f = h5py.File(myfile)
```

The dataset:

```
In [81]: f['mylist']
Out[81]: <HDF5 dataset "mylist": shape (2, 1), type "|S10">
```

load it:

```
In [82]: f['mylist'][:]
Out[82]: 
array([[b'abc1'],
       [b'def2']], dtype='|S10')
```

That's a bytestring array, shape (2,1) (as you specified).

As unicode:

```
In [83]: f['mylist'][:].astype('U10')
Out[83]: 
array([['abc1'],
       ['def2']], dtype='<U10')
```

As a flattened list:

```
In [84]: f['mylist'][:].astype('U10').ravel().tolist()
Out[84]: ['abc1', 'def2']
```